# Criação de ambiente de deploy com linux Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, deploy, groovy

Estou testando uma máquina da Digital Ocean, ela vem com o linux Ubuntu(eu escolhi), eu preciso criar o seguinte ambiente

```
Firewall    
Java
Tomcat7
Jenkins
git
MySQL
MySqlAdmin
Groovy
Gradle
```

Bem, como podem ver, preciso de um ambiente completo para deploy, pergunto, tem algum "pacote" que já instale tudo isso?

Eu gostaria de criar um "script" que eu rode e ele vá configurando o sistema para adequar a esse ambiente, eu já fiz a instalação de boa parte mas queria saber se tem como eu criar um script que rode no linux para eu não ter que se precisar no futuro, ficar instalando tudo manual.

Resumindo, eu quero automatizar o processo de configuração de ambiente para deploy no linux Ubuntu.

Eu estava testando o Openshift, nele eu não preciso configurar nada, mas estou tendo dificuldades para fazer o gradle compilar o groovy, está dando erros de permissões, o firewall deles está bloqueando, está complicado.

Se também houvesse alguma solução já pronta para hospedar de forma simples que tivesse tudo isso seria legal

Comment: Vc tem um sistema que é desenvolvido que deseja que a cada nova versão seja feita a publicação automatica nesse ambiente, é isso?

Comment: Quem faz a publicação é o Jenkins, eu queria instalar tudo isso através de um script ou se conhece alguma hospedagem que facilite um deploy eficiente da aplicação

Comment: Amazon, da uma olhada aqui
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63042/como-automatizar-o-processo-de-deploy/63051#63051

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiro você utilizar o [Ansible](https://serversforhackers.com/an-ansible-tutorial). É exatamente o que você precisa, uma ferramente de configuração que permite você configurar seus servidores.

Em uma visão simplista, o Ansible é praticamente um shell script com seus comandos de instalação e configuração, mas uma importante diferença, e o motivo pelo qual é melhor você utilizar o Ansible, é que este é **idempotente**: se você tiver um script Ansible que instala, por exemplo, o `git` em seu servidor, e você executar esse script 8 vezes, o `git` só será instalado na primeira vez. Nas 7 vezes seguintes o Ansible verifica que o `git` já está instalado, e que não faz sentido tentar instalá-lo novamente. Enquanto que se você executasse um simples shell script para instalar o `git`, ele iria dar erro e, dependendo do caso, poderia até comprometer seu servidor.

Ansible é uma ferramente madura, grandemente utilizada e com diversas opções, então recomendo você encontrar um tutorial a seu gosto sobre, ou então a própria [documentação](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/index.html). Recomendo [este tutorial](https://serversforhackers.com/an-ansible-tutorial).

Abaixo segue um pequeno passo-a-passo para instalar apenas o `git` em um servidor. Não vou colocar a forma completa para instalar todos seus programas porque isso seria monstruoso (para a resposta e para mim :)) e porque diversas dessas ferramentes têm pequenos detalhes que você deve configurar na instalação.

### Tutorial bem básico do Ansible

Primeiro ponto importante: você **não precisa** instalar o Ansible no seu servidor (o qual você quer configurar), apenas em alguma outra máquina (pode ser seu computador em casa) que tenha acesso, via SSH, ao servidor a ser configurado.

Instale o Ansible na sua máquina (estou supondo que seja Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:ansible/ansible
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y ansible
```

Edite o arquivo `/etc/ansible/hosts` para conter o IP do(s) servidor(es) que você deseja configurar (pode ser mais que um):

```
[web]
192.168.22.10
192.168.22.11
```

Crie um `playbook`, que é a coleção de comandos a serem executados pelo ansible. O `playbook` é um arquivo em formato [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML), e deve ser salvo com a extensão `.yml`. Exemplo de um `playbook` que instala o programa `git` em servidores Ubuntu:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Instalando git
      apt: pkg=git state=installed update_cache=true
```

`apt: pkg=git state=installed update_cache=true` indica que Ansible deve executar o módulo `apt`, o qual deve instalar o programa `git`, e espera-se que o resultado final da execução seja o `git` instalado (`state=installed`).

E para executar esse `playbook`, no terminal digite:

```
$ ansible-playbook -s -k -u USUARIO --ask-become-pass ARQUIVO.yml
```

- `ansible-playbook` é o comando do Ansible para executar os comandos de um `plabook`;
- `-s` indica que você quer que os comandos a serem executado no servidor sejam executados como `sudo`;
- `-k` indica que você quer passar a senha para logar via SSH no servidor;
- `-u USUARIO` indica que Ansible deve logar como `USUARIO` no servidor (se você não passar esse parâmetro Ansible irá utilizar o mesmo usuário da sua máquina local, o qual nem sempre é o mesmo do servidor);
- `--ask-become-pass` indica que você deseja informar a senha `sudo` do servidor, para que Ansible consiga executar, nesse exemplo, o comando `sudo apt-get git`;
- `ARQUIVO.yml` indica o seu arquivo `playbook`.

Comment: Apesar do tempo sua resposta está certa, eu estou hoje utilizando o ansible e docker, mas não uso mais Java rsrsrsrs, graças a Deus estou no Python! obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: Realmente, a resposta chegou um pouco atrasada :), mas pelo menos fica de referência para outras pessoas que tiverem a mesma dúvida. E que bom que você encontrou a luz e largou Java haha.