# Como automatizar o processo de deploy?

Tags: servidor, tomcat, deploy, jenkins

Utilizando o Jenkins, para obter as mudanças de uma branch e **mandar imediatamente para produção** quais são as maneiras de montar a infra-estrutura do servidor? 
Digo, existe outra possibilidade de fazer isso além de possuir mais de uma máquina, "desviar" as requisições e derrubar somente uma das máquinas para poder fazer o deploy? 
Como fica o banco de dados?

Comment: Olá, Daniela. Infelizmente acho que esta pergunta é realmente muito ampla. Existem muitas maneiras de montar uma infra de integração contínua. Não é algo trivial, depende do projeto, da equipe, da empresa, das tecnologias. Não tem como responder à pergunta de forma completa sem escrever um livro sobre *Integração Contínua com Jenkins*. Minha sugestão é procurar livros ou tutoriais ara montar uma infra básica e depois adicionar coisas mais complexas como deploy em clusters. Configurar CI não é tarefa para um desenvolvedor iniciando. Muitas empresas terão alguém dedicado só a isto.

Comment: Mas mosso responder especificamente sua dúvida sobre atualização de mais de um servidor com "desvio". Sim, isto não somente é possível como é feito por empresas ágeis. Meu atual colega aqui na empresa trabalhou no UOL em São Paulo e já conversamos sobre a infra de lá. Eles possuem 6 servidores em clusters, mas não atualizam todos automaticamente. Após a versão do sistema ser publicada no servidor de CI, eles atualizam um dos servidores para testes de qualidade, desviando os usuários normais para os outros 5. Depois, eles colocam em dois dos seis e liberam apenas para alguns usuários.

Comment: @utluiz Realmente. É muito curioso saber como funciona em grandes empresas, obrigada por compartilhar. Achei esse link que descreve um pouco do Facebook e Netflix, se interessar alguém:
http://blog.octo.com/pt-br/os-padroes-dos-gigantes-da-web-o-zero-downtime-deployment/

http://blog.octo.com/pt-br/os-padroes-dos-gigantes-da-web-deploy-continuo/

Comment: Se não houver ocorrências, então o deploy é feito nos demais servidores. Cada passo é disparado manualmente, mas todo o processo é automatizado. Dessa forma eles podem funcionar 24/7 sem interrupção. A dificuldade para chegar a um nível desses é que não basta só configurar um Jenkins, mas toda a empresa precisa absorver o processo, desde o planejamento de novas *features* até o teste de aceitação do usuário e QA.

Comment: Muito bom, Daniela! Você está indo pelo caminho certo. Há muito material bom disponível na Internet. Só é preciso garimpar um pouco, se dedicar a ler, pesquisar os pontos que ainda não conhece e aliar tudo isto à prática, implementando protótipos e testando as ferramentas.